# How to add params in php Slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I used Slim framework as background to call API.

I have configed `composer.json` file:

```
{
  "require": {
     "slim/slim": "^2.6",
     "slim/middleware": "*"
  },
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {"App\\Controller\\": "server/controllers/"}
  }
}
```

And `index.php` file:

```
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 $configs = array(  'mode'=>'development',
                'debug'=>true, 
                'log.enabled' => true,
                'templates.path' => './templates',
                'cookies.secret_key' => 'secret'
            );
$app = new \Slim\Slim($configs);

$app->get('/login', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('login.php');
});

$app->post('/login', function() use ($app) {
   $process= new App\Controller\MiddleProcess();
   // process request to call API 
   $process->transferRequest();
});

$app->run();
?>
```

I had a file `MiddleProcess.php` in directory `server/controllers/`:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;
class MiddleProcess {
 public $url = 'http://api.com/';
 function transferRequest() {
     $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
     $post_datas = $app->request->post();
     $token = $app->getCookie('token');
     $url = $this->url.'/login';
     // How can I add param: `$token` and change 'url', then continue to call API here
     // example: http://api.com/login?access_token=$token

 }
} 
 ?>
```

How to change `url` request and add param `access_token`. Then continue to  call API?

Comment: if you want to simply redirect, my answer below should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `redirect` method of slim.

```
//first merge any existing get params with our token param and build the query string.
$query_string = http_build_query(array_merge($app->request->get(),['access_token'=>$token]));
//call app redirect
$app->redirect($url.'?'.$query_string));
```

Comment: Thanks @r3wt. I understand your solution is `redirect` . But how about `POST` parameters: `username`, `password` ?

Comment: @datnq read [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect).

Comment: @datnq seems like a poor architechtural choice to me. personally, i use the slim.before hook to do auth, then redirect with the token from there. if its of type post and there is no session set, then you shouldn't give a crap anyway IMO, and in that case you should redirect to the login form

Comment: @r3wt:  yes, i know that I can use  `hooking` or `middleware` to authenticate. 
But in my project, I have to use `token` to call API. If not login `token` is `API_KEY`. 
I found the solution is `GuzzleHttp`  to make `request`